# Javascript Intellisense in Microsoft Visual Studio objects defined by custom code define / derive

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, object, intellisense

**Situation: using functions to declare your Classes**

If you are using and declaring classes with some custom (or framework function) as WinJs does (check their open source git directory), you are certainly familiar with this kind of code:

function define(constructor, instanceMembers, staticMembers) { }

function derive(baseClass, constructor, instanceMembers, staticMembers) { }

```
define(function constructor(){
   this.yourProperty = 1;
}, {
   // Prototype object
   somePrototypeFunction: function(){
      // When you type "this." here, it will not show up "yourProperty" declared 
      // in the constructor, because you have not instanciated the class, 
      // intellisense does not know that everything is linked
   }
}
```

**Common problem on these "custom" functions**

Intellisense does not show up the values declared within the constructor when you try to reach them from the prototype functions.

I found something that have helped me: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsapps/en-US/3eee400a-fefd-4f5e-9109-68df03fef006/javascript-intellisense-with-this-inside-gettersetter

This leaded me to the solution that I share to you below, it was a pain to make it work, and actually I was about to ** AGAIN ** let go with that problem which was something really disapointing especially with big team projects. 
I find it weird that there are not many complaints about this on the web, maybe it's a configuration problem? However I had that problem on all VSD installations I saw.

So I hope the following solution will help you too if you run into the same situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few hours I finally have a solution which is not perfect (I have handled .base like in C# in my javascript library, but with the following code I can't say to intellisense that this ".base(...) " exists in the context of the prototype functions and constructor). If you have any tip on how to do that let me know, I'm interested.

Tested on Visual Studio 2013.

- Simply change window.define / window.derive to the namespace and name you actually use (for WinJs it would be WinJS.Class.define and WinJS.Class.derive).
- Add in _references.js the relative path of the file where you will put the following code, just after your library

And that's all! You'll have intellisense inside your

---

```
(function (window) {
    "use strict";
    /*
     * Goal: make intellisense understand that the constructor of your define/derive functions are linked to the prototype object you have supplied. 
     * Tested on WinJs library and other custom libraries.
     * Save this in a file, and reference it only in _references.js, insert it after your library containing the define/derive functions
    */

    function initIntellisenseFor(constructor, baseClass) {
        var inst = new constructor();
        // Force intellisense to run function
        for (var key in inst) {
            if (typeof inst[key] == 'function') {
                try {
                    inst[key]();
                } catch (e) {
                    // Silent fail if wrong arguments (not sure if needed)
                }
            }                
        }
        // Force intellisense to discover constructor
        inst.constructor = constructor;

        // Missing: .base() implementation for each method with redirection to the appropriate parent class method
    }

    var oldDefine = window.define;
    window.define = function (constructor, instanceMembers, staticMembers) {
        var result = oldDefine.call(this, constructor, instanceMembers, staticMembers);
        initIntellisenseFor(result);
        return result;
    };

    var oldDerive = window.derive;
    window.derive = function (baseClass, constructor, instanceMembers, staticMembers) {
        var result = oldDerive.call(this, baseClass, constructor, instanceMembers, staticMembers);
        initIntellisenseFor(result, baseClass);
        return result;
    };

})(this);
```